# Angularjs No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: c#, angularjs, json

Im getting Error as:

> Failed to load http://localhost:10948/Api/Home/PostData/[object%20Object]: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:57580' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Even i have Access-controll Orion File in my WebAPi(Global.asax.cs)File

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
            string[] allowedOrigin = new string[] { "http://localhost:57580", "http://localhost:11518" };
            var origin = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Origin"];
            if (origin != null && allowedOrigin.Contains(origin))
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST");
            }
```

**Angular.js**

```
$scope.SubmitForm = function (isValied) {
        var EmployeeDetails = {
            'Empname': $scope.Emp.EmpName
        }
        if (isValied) {
       EmployeeFactoryService.SaveEmployeee(EmployeeDetails).then(function ()

            })
        }       
    }
```

**Factory.Js**

```
EmployeeFactoryServices.SaveEmployeee = function (Employee) {
    return $http({
        url: 'http://localhost:10948/Api/Home/PostData/'+ Employee,
        method: 'POST',
        ContentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my JavaScript get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error when Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)

Comment: You don't have to worry about the Origin header just set the header to all the allowed origin and the browser will handle the rest ;)

Comment: You also need to be sure to handle OPTIONS preflight requests in your routing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the way you configure CORS as follows,

```
  HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            //These headers are handling the "pre-flight" OPTIONS call sent by the browser
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, OPTIONS");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
```

also the request should be,

```
 return $http({
        url: 'http://localhost:10948/Api/Home/PostData/'+ ,
        method: 'POST',
        data : Employee,
        ContentType: 'application/json' })
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a chrome extensions cors.
Use it and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

1- as I can see from your URL that the object you are trying to send didn't stringified so I recommend to stringify it using `JSON.stringify(EmployeeDetails)`

2- you'd better use `Content-Type:application/json` for your post requests.

3- you have to allow requests from your client side application into your backend code

4- you can overcome this temporarily via [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en)